# How do I toggle DOM elements to show and hide

Tags: javascript, css, click, toggle, show-hide

On my index.JS file, I created elements using documentCreateElement and appended them to the DOM to show data from an api. Then I created an event listener which works where if I click my H3 element, it will show my H4 and P element. But I want it to where if I click my H3 element again, I want the H4 and P elements to hide. This is the code I have for my click event listener:

```
`H3.addEventListener(‘click’, clickFunction) 

Function clickFunction() {
Div.append(h4) 
Div.append(p)
}`
```

Can someone please help me?

I tried to look up toggling functions online or incorporate CSS hidden class to the h4 and p elements but nothing was hiding

Comment: Try to use removeChild() command...

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying your clickFunction() to check if the elements are already displayed or not.

```
let isDisplayed = false;

function clickFunction() {
  if (isDisplayed) {
    // If the elements are already displayed, hide them
    h4.style.display = "none";
    p.style.display = "none";
    isDisplayed = false;
  } else {
    // If the elements are not displayed, show them
    div.appendChild(h4);
    div.appendChild(p);
    isDisplayed = true;
  }
}

h3.addEventListener("click", clickFunction);
```

In above example, its a boolean variable **isDisplayed** to keep track of whether the elements are currently displayed or not. When the h3 element is clicked, the **clickFunction()** is called, and it checks the value of **isDisplayed**. If its true, it means the elements are already displayed, so we hide them by setting their display style to "none" and setting **isDisplayed** to false. If it's false, it means the elements are not displayed, so we show them by appending them to the div and setting **isDisplayed** to true.

Note that you'll need to deeclare the **isDisplayed** variable outside of the **clickFunction()** so that its value is preserved between function calls. And make sure to select the h4, p, and div elements using **document.querySelector()** or a smilar method before using them in the function.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in your `clickFunction`

```js
Function clickFunction() {
  if(!Div.hasChildNodes()) {
    Div.append(h4)
    Div.append(p)
  } else {
    Div.removeChild(Div.childNodes(0))
    Div.removeChild(Div.childNodes(1))
  }
}
```

Check [this](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_haschildnodes.asp) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below steps-

1. Find the existing `p` and `h4` elements.
2. If found then remove those using the `removeChild` method, else append those using the `append` method.

Here is a working demo of toggling the elements-

```js
let h3 = document.querySelector('h3');
h3.addEventListener('click', clickFunction)

let div = document.querySelector('div');

function clickFunction() {
  // Find already exists p and h4 elements
  let p_exists = document.querySelector('p');
  let h4_exists = document.querySelector('h4');
  
  // If found then remove one by one
  if (p_exists && h4_exists) {
    div.removeChild(h4_exists);
    div.removeChild(p_exists);
  } 
  
  // Else, create and append
  else {
    let h4 = document.createElement('h4')
    h4.innerText = "I am a h4 element";

    let p = document.createElement('p')
    p.innerText = "I am a p element";
    
    div.append(h4, p);
  }
}
```

```html
<h3>Click</h3>
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a CSS style rule and checking for the existence of the CSS style rule class name on each HTML element's class list is a common method for toggling the display state of an element.

I used a `hide` class name in the code snippet but you can change to a 'show' class name with some minor modifications to the code and CSS rules.

```js
var H3 = document.getElementById("h3-elem");
H3.addEventListener("click", clickFunction);

var Div = document.getElementById("div-elem");

function clickFunction() {
  var h4 = document.getElementById("h4-elem");
  var p = document.getElementById("p-elem");

  if (!h4) {
    h4 = appendH4();
  }
  if (!p) {
    p = appendP();
  }

  // Option 1:
  // Use the built-in 'toggle()' method on the class list
  // for each element.
  // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/toggle
  // h4.classList.toggle("hide");
  // p.classList.toggle("hide");

  // Option 2:
  // Check if the class list for the 'h4' and 'p' elements 
  // contain 'hide' class name. If the class list does not
  // contain the class name then add the 'hide' class name
  // to the class list.
  if (h4.classList.contains("hide")) {
    h4.classList.remove("hide");
  } else {
    h4.classList.add("hide");
  }

  if (p.classList.contains("hide")) {
    p.classList.remove("hide");
  } else {
    p.classList.add("hide");
  }
}

// Set to hide initially. After creation of the element,
// the 'clickFunction' will determine the display state
// of the element by checking for the existense of the
// 'hide' class name.

function appendH4() {
  var h4 = document.createElement("h4");
  h4.id = "h4-elem";
  h4.className = "hide";
  h4.textContent = "Header 4";
  Div.append(h4);
  return h4;
}

function appendP() {
  var p = document.createElement("p");
  p.id = "p-elem";
  p.className = "hide";
  p.textContent = "A paragraph";
  Div.append(p);
  return p;
}
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<h3 id="h3-elem">Header 3</h3>
<div id="div-elem"></div>
```